# Should tags be restrictive or descriptive?

Tags: discussion, tags

Case in point:

[Is it practical and worthwhile to fit old SLR lenses to mirrorless digital cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/is-it-practical-and-worthwhile-to-fit-old-slr-lenses-to-mirrorless-digital-camer)

This talks about both the Sony NEX and Micro Four Thirds. Should this have only the broader, generic tag, or should it have tags for both of the more specific systems in addition (or instead)?

If I'm using the exclusion feature of tags, and I hate Sony, I might miss out on a question actually interesting to me due to overly-specific tagging. Is that something we care about, or is it more overridingly useful to have more descriptive tags?

Comment: From the [SO FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879): "Try to use broad tags." That advice, of course, assumes a programming Q&A context, so it has to be re-interpreted as appropriate for the photography site. But it's useful guidance concerning how tags are *intended* to work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm of the opinion that tags should reflect the *specialist knowledge required to answer the question*; so maybe [old-lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-lenses) and [micro-four-thirds](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micro-four-thirds) and [lens-adapter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens-adapter); had the Sony mount been specific, then by all means have [sony](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sony) instead of micro 4/3

Comment: So why _not_ [tag:sony-nex] in this case?

Comment: Good point, not being a sony specialist, I'd misread, and thought the Sony NEX was a 4/3 mount as well...

Comment: I agree. The tags should reflect the amount of knowledge required to answer the question.